# Checked is not accepted from backend. Is there another way

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a mailchimp form there is looking like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[7][1]" id="mce-group[7]-7-0" checked></input>
```

The CMS system I am using have a HTML validator. That validator is not accepting `checked` as a validt html tag... Therefore I cannot publish my code. Is there another way to set set `checked`? Fx `checked="checked"`?

Comment: what does that mean? "The backend system is not accepting..." "checked" is a valid attribute in checkbox-inputs. Do you get an error-message in the console? Is the checkbox simply not "checked" by default?

Comment: The CMS system I am using has a HTML validator. That validator is not accepting the html tag as valid, even if it is valid.

Comment: Then it sounds like a broken HTML-validator. Have a look at this https://organicweb.com.au/19886/email-marketing/html-checkbox-selected/

Comment: It is a general problem, so they backenders took a decision not to validate it. Thanks for the link. That is my problem there is described there, To sign people into groups in Mailchimp you need the html tag checked. If that is not in your form, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to do like this: `checked="checked"`.